# MongoEngine add hashed shared key in Meta

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a sharded MongoDB collection. Below is a test MongoDB model:

```
class Test(Document):
   some_id = ObjectIdField(required=True)
   meta = {
        "auto_create_index": False,
        "index_background": True,
        "indexes": [{"fields": ["+some_id"]}],
        "shard_key": ("some_id_hashed",),
    }
```

I'm following the mongoEngine document for the [shard_key](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=shard_key#shard-keys). However, when I run the `save` it'll fail with this error:

```
File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 485, in _save_update
val = val[ak]
KeyError: 'some_id_hashed'
```

I have created a hashed index for some id `db.collection.createIndex( { some_id: "hashed" } )`

Does anybody know how I should do the save with hashed_shard_key?

Answer (score 0):

The shard key must be an existing field of the model, so it should be `some_id` in this case

Comment: In my case, I was to use a hashed key for the shard key. Are you suggesting that I add the some_id_hashed to the model?

Comment: This might work but I agree that it sounds like a dirty workaround. I have limited experience with sharding but perhaps you are right and there is a bug in MongoEngine or simply no support for it. Open a ticket in the githib repo and post a working example with pymongo (the underlying driver), this may help to have it resolved